# Command Line Arguments to Azure Webjobs

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs

I'm in the process of migrating a couple of Jobs that were previously scheduled and run through Quartz.Net to Azure Webjobs.

Using Quartz.Net allowed me to have all the (very compact) Job Classes in the same project as the console program entry point initializing the scheduler.

Now I would like to retain that structure without having to create a discrete console application project for each and every web job.

Is there currently any way to configure a command line argument for continuous web-job that would allow to branch internally to the correct job depending on the command line argument?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Azure WebJobs one way to do this is to create a script file for each WebJob with the command line arguments: `MyApplication.exe arg1 arg2`.

Another would be to select the method to run by the current WebJob name which you can get from the environment variable **WEBJOBS_NAME**.

For triggered WebJobs there is support for command line arguments (per run) in the API but it is still unsupported by the Azure portal: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#invoke-a-triggered-job.

Comment: I've been experimenting with ps-scripts as intermediate but WEBJOBS_NAME sounds good as well.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more about the first option you mentioned - creating a script with parameters? How to tell the web job to run a script instead of executing the console app exe? Also I can't see any env variables referring to webjobs in my kudu console.

Comment: @andy250 create a run.cmd file with your script, it will always be the script selected to run. you won't see the env variables of a webjob on kudu console as it's not running as a webjob, you can create a webjob with a script that prints out all env variables and then look at the log.