# Can multiple Azure webjobs share the same assemblies?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have an Azure WebJob that needs to be run 4 different ways and at different times, using 4 different command line parameters.  I can set the parameters with a run.cmd but it seems like a waste of space to have 4 sets of assemblies.  Can multiple webjobs be defined that run the same set of assemblies, from the same folder. Each webjobs would just have a single run.cmd that called the exe from that folder.

Comment: Please see Amit's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24865828/command-line-arguments-to-azure-webjobs/24870411#24870411

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible out of the box.

There is a way to do it though but at a cost, you can have one directory with your binaries (at some place on your site for example: `d:\home\site\wwwroot\app_data\jobs\common`) and have your WebJobs only as one `run.cmd` script each with the proper arguments calling to that common directory:

```
@echo off
d:\home\site\wwwroot\app_data\jobs\common\DoWork.exe job1
```

The problem is the update story, when you need to update these common WebJobs binaries you'll first have to stop your WebJobs since the files will probably be locked and start them afterwards.

Comment: If the jobs are triggered, then I would not need to stop them?

Comment: You can't stop a triggered webjob, so you'll need them to stop by themselves or restart the site. you could follow one more step which is copy the common directory to some temporary directory (`%temp%\something`) before running the webjob and then running it from that directory. This will help not locking the files.

Comment: Also you should better use `WEBROOT_PATH` environment variable instead of hard-coding the `d:\home\site\wwwroot` path.

Comment: @Martin while WebJobs copy the binaries before running them (to avoind the locking issue) in this scenario the only file copied is the `run.cmd` but the binaries themselves remain uncopied and will be locked. `WEBROOT_PATH` would work, also `HOME` works.

Comment: Might be better then, from a maintenance perspective, to have the batch file clone the shared assemblies to its temp folder (`%WEBJOBS_PATH`).

Comment: Above solution works for me. But there is issue with configuration. If exe file is deployed with web project then job have access to all app settings and connection string that are configured in the "config" section of web site. In case of run as cmd only settings from app.config are available.
Does anyone know how to avoid this issue?

Comment: You can find all app settings and connection strings in the Environment